# Black screen on Win7 after booting

Tags: windows-7, boot, display

i have problem. My computer (is an automative B&R) is all of time after booting goes to black screen . I booting from CFast card. I try many monitors, video cable, Safe mode, Lowest resolution, Last good booting but always the same.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Did it ever work before?  You can also you try to boot something else, like portable Linux to learn whether the black screen is caused specifically by Windows or whether there is a problem with video mode regardless of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl`+ `Alt` and `Del` to start task manager. 
From here end the current `explorer.exe` and start a new `explorer.exe` task. If this works it may be a virus high jacking your boot.

If not, whilst in Task Manager clear any unknown process and services that may be beneficial. Next start `cmd.exe` and run `sfc.exe /scannow`. You might need to confirm that code. Just use `sfc.exe` and see the parameters.

Lastly try `chkdsk` to see if there are any HDD errors on the PC. Let me know how you go.